# Unexpected controller and action values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am viewing my parameters when testing my ruby on rails application, and the controller and action values are not what I would expect based on the routes.rb file or when running "rake routes".

For example, the URL http://localhost:3000/crimpers/1
yields the parameters of:

```
{ controller: ecrimp, action: show, id: 1}
```

whereas I would expect it to be:

```
{ controller: crimpers, action: show, id:1 }
```

However, for http://localhost:3000/crimpers, the parameters are the expected:

```
{ controller: crimpers, action: index }
```

crimpers_controller.rb contains the actions index, create, update, edit, show, new and destroy.
ecrimp_controller.rb contains the actions welcome and ecrimp.

routes.rb:

```
  root 'ecrimp#welcome'    
  get 'ecrimp' => 'ecrimp#ecrimp'    
  resources :crimpers    
  resources :hose_specs    
  resources :hose_specs do     
  collection { post :import }
```

Why might the controller and action be defined in such a way for the first url?

Comment: Is that the complete contents of your routes file?

Comment: Did you try to restart your server after editing routes.rb?

Comment: @RobWagner, that is my complete routes file

Comment: @Walerian, yes I had tried to restart the server, but it didn't fix anything.